# AsyncTask in a Loop In Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-inflate

I am creating a app that will update the weather details of the city.The loop will be a List of City .So i want as much the cities are in there in the List.I will use the  AsyncTask method to send the request and parse it.And at the same time i am inflating a layout and i have to put all the weather details corresponding to the city in the Layout .How could i achieve this please help me in this.

**XML** file that i am inflating

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/depart_details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flight_depart_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/f1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/depart_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flight_depart_image"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/depart_airport_city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/depart_time"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/depart_airport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/depart_airport_city"
        android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
        android:text="N/A"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/weather_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft ="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/depart_airport"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tempraturetext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/weather_image"
        android:text="Temp:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/temprature"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tempraturetext"
        android:text="20℃" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/humidity_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/temprature"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/weather_image"
        android:text="Humidity:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/humidity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/temprature"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/humidity_text"
        android:text="32" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/depart_airport"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#d3d3d3" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

this function i have created to send the request

```
private WeatherResponse requestWeatherUpdate(String location) {
        url = "" + location; //This location will be dyanamic and multiple
        Log.d("URL for Weather Upadate", url);
        WeatherUpdate weatherReq = new WeatherUpdate(new CallBack() {
            @Override
            public void run(Object result) {
                try {
                     AppResponse = (String) result;
                    response = ParseWeatherResponseXML
                            .parseMyTripXML(AppResponse);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TAG Exception Occured",
                            "Exception is " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        weatherReq.execute(url);
        return response;

    }
```

**AsynkTask**

```
public class WeatherUpdate extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context context;
    CallBack callBack;

    public WeatherUpdate(CallBack callBack) {
        this.callBack = callBack;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String responseString = "";
        HttpClient client = null;
        try {
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(IweenTripDetails.url);
            client.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 6000);
            client.getParams().setParameter("http.connection.timeout", 6000);
            HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);
            HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();
            if (resEntityGet != null) {
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
                Log.i("GET RESPONSE", responseString.trim());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC_ERROR", "Error is " + e.toString());
        }
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC_RESPONSE", responseString.trim());
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        return responseString.trim();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        callBack.run(result);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Instead of Keeping AsynChronous Task into Loop, Keep Loop inside AsynChronous. and use `onProgressUpdate` to update UI.

**Updated for Example Code**

```
public class Asyn extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        for (String location : params) {
            String tmp = getTemp(location);
            publishProgress(tmp);    /** Use Result **/
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate Weather
     * 
     * @param location
     * @return
     */
    private String getTemp(String location) {
        return location;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.e("Temo", values[0]);
    }

}
```

And Pass the array of Location where you start process

```
        Asyn m = new Asyn();
    String arrryaLocation = null; // your vales
    m.execute(arrryaLocation);
```

Comment: this should be comment.

Comment: @sameer please elaborate more how could i do this by your way

Comment: See i have to infalate the XML as well as with in the loop and have to put the values that i will recive from the response .How i have to do that i am not getting that

Comment: use every line of code inside    private String getTemp(String location) {
        return location;
    }

Comment: and you can change you method name, return type, paramter according to your requiremen

Comment: Please comment on my code where i have to make the chages i am not geeting you

Comment: @Sameer please help me in  this ...I need help

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 methods in Asynctask , Make your HTTP call and Parse data in doInBackground() Method which is used to do background processes and inflate Layout inonPostExecute Method which is used to do UI operations.

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //Make your HTTP call and parse data

            return null;
    }
```

and UI interaction

```
@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Inflate layout here
        }
```

Comment: this should be comment

Answer (score 0):

```
  class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>    {


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //parseing all details
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // set up values for required params
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            //make the web service call here
            return null;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: run a loop inside the doInBackground

Comment: I think this comment should be added in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example for **getting data from server and store it into DB**

Here i am **updating UI with total number of data which is inserted in DB**

```
  private class async extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean>
    {
            Context context;
            ProgressDialog pd;
            boolean flag ;
            Progress progress;

            async(Context mcontext)
            {
                context = mcontext; 
                pd = new ProgressDialog(activityContext);
                progress = new Progress(this);
            } 

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
            {
                pd.setTitle("Loading..");

                pd.setMessage("Please Wait...!  " + NO + "  Record Inserted");
                pd.setCancelable(false);
                pd.show();
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) 
            {

                return flag = = getData(progress);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) 
            {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

                pd.setMessage("Please Wait..." + values[0].toString());
            }

            public class Progress 
            {
                public async task;

                public Progress(async task) 
                {
                    this.task = task;
                }

                public void publish(String value) 
                {
                    task.publishProgress(value);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) 
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                if(pd.isShowing()) pd.dismiss();
            }
}
```

**Here is GetData Class:**

```
public boolean getData(Progress progress) 
        {

            while(true) // here you can use your loop 
            {
                try
                {
                    SoapObject soReturn ;

                    if(soReturn != null)
                    {

                No = mNumber; // here i am getting total number is inserted in db
                    progress.publish(No); // No is published and sent it to progress update method.


            return true ;
        }
```

Call it with

```
new async(context).execute();
```

Hope it will help you.